# Why Qml's function cannot control any object's opacity, visible?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am writing an application with Qt and use Qml to define the UI. But then I found a big problem: In my app, the C++ code sends a signal and I define a function in Qml to receive the signal. But I found that in the Qml function, **some codes just don't work**, like:

```
function receive_signal() {
    console.log("Running");
    button1.opacity = 1; // button1 is a id of my Button item and its initial value is 0
    button2.visible = true; // button2 is a id of my Button item and its initial value is false
    console.log("Running too");
}
```

The console has printed `Running` and `Running too`, **but the two buttons don't appear, which means that those two line codes don't work**.

I don't why and hope anyone can help me.

Comment: What are the visible and opacity states of the button parents?

Comment: `opacity` and `visible` work fine with `Button` so most likely there is some error in your code. Show the code where `button1` and `buton2` were defined.

Comment: error or maybe they have a width and height of 0.